# Get a list of discriminator values in a JPA and Hibernate inheritance tree

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, orm

Is there a utility in Hibernate to quickly get a list of discriminator values that exist within an inheritance tree? It would be useful to avoid hard-coding this in certain SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the discriminator column to one property of your inheritance model base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 255)
public class BaseEntity { 

    @Column(name = "discriminator", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String discriminator;

}
```

### Update

In HQL queries you can also use the *class* directive:

```
select e.class, e.id from YourEntity e
```

For SQL queries you can only use the predefined discriminator column. There's no utility to help you with that. Hibernate utilities are target towards entity queries (HQL or Criteria).

Comment: I get that. In my case I have a SQL query (not HQL) in which I have to select items based on the appropriate discriminators. I don't want to depend on hardcoding those, since I might add a new child and forget to add it to the SQL query. Hence my question.